# How to stop rollback in TestNG?

Tags: java, spring, testng, rollback

I have a test like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:war/WEB-INF/application-context.xml" })
public class ServiceImplTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Rollback(false)
    @Test
    public void testCreate()
    {
           .....
              //save an entity to table_A
      service.save(a);
    }
}
```

The table_A will be cleaned up; how to stop this cleaning action?

Answer (score 0):

Try marking your test class as transactional, which will require you to use springs test classes also.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class),
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:war/WEB-INF/application-context.xml" })
@Transactional
public class ServiceImplTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void testCreate()
    {
           .....
              //save an entity to table_A
      service.save(a);
    }
}
```

You could also try using `@TransactionConfiguration`, where txMgr is the name of your transaction manager.:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class),
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:war/WEB-INF/application-context.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager="txMgr", defaultRollback=false)
public class ServiceImplTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
  ....
}
```

The rollback functionality in test is dependent on how you manage your transactions, without that information it is hard to give you a solid answer.

Comment: It seems not roolback but clean first,because after each test,all old data entries in the table disppeared,only the entry that is inserted by test is left.